# How to make a Google script call to a Django Rest framework

Tags: google-apps-script, django-rest-framework

I have a an API available as a Django rest framework. I would like to make it available as a google sheet using Google script as less tech guys are more used to Exel. This a sample body with the input data I'm using with postman to do a post request:

```
{
    "Group": {
        "Names": [
            "Peter",
            "John",
            "Marry"
        ],
        "weightsColumns": [
            "Peter",
            "John",
            "Marry"
        ],
        "weightsIndex": [
            0,
            1,
            2
        ],
        "weightsValues": [
            [
                0.848324434,
                0.00129090761,
                0.00000549100261
            ],
            [
                0.68104794,
                0.00000594297639,
                0.00000477060816
            ],
            [
                0.496659891,
                0.00000495070405,
                0.00000227036433
            ],
            [
                0.326632792,
                0.0000148350248,
                0.00000133351815
            ]
        ]
    },
    "DataColumns": [
        "Scale1",
        "Scale2",
        "Scale3"
    ],
    "DataValues": [
        [
            0,
            10,
            100
        ]
    ],
    "DataIndex": [
        0,
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Now how can I do such an API call with Google script. My attempt so far following the official documentation

```
    var data =     {
            "Group": {
                "Names": [
                    "Peter",
                    "John",
                    "Marry"
                ],
                "weightsColumns": [
                    "Peter",
                    "John",
                    "Marry"
                ],
                "weightsIndex": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                "weightsValues": [
                    [
                        0.848324434,
                        0.00129090761,
                        0.00000549100261
                    ],
                    [
                        0.68104794,
                        0.00000594297639,
                        0.00000477060816
                    ],
                    [
                        0.496659891,
                        0.00000495070405,
                        0.00000227036433
                    ],
                    [
                        0.326632792,
                        0.0000148350248,
                        0.00000133351815
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "DataColumns": [
                "Scale1",
                "Scale2",
                "Scale3"
            ],
            "DataValues": [
                [
                    0,
                    10,
                    100
                ]
            ],
            "DataIndex": [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        };
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'ApiKey name:XXXXXX',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch('sampleurl', options);
```

However with that I get an error with a bad request. But the data is working with postman so that I believe I handle the request wrongly with google script. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing as so:

```
var options = {
  "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
       "Content-type": "application/json",
   },
  "method": "POST",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

use the `headers` key for `Authorization` and `Content-type`. Not sure if you need `Bearer` with your api call